# Property 'dismiss' does not exist on type 'ModalController'

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm following this doc about Modal in Ionic Angular (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal).
I've found this problem and cannot figure out the way to solve.

I'm currently using this version: @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

```
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

 dismiss() {
    this.modalController.dismiss({
      'dismissed': true
    });
  }
```

Error:

```
Property 'dismiss' does not exist on type 'ModalController'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your import to this:

`import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';`

Comment: I tried this but it prints "Cannot find module '@ionic/angular' or its corresponding type declarations."

Comment: @ChuwongKul what version of Ionic is your project running?

Comment: I've found the solution. It works when I update the Ionic version of my project. Thanks so much for your time :)